<java.io.NotSerializableException: javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty> how to serialize a propertyString in javafx
First I really appreciate any assitance from the community! Thanks a lot!!!!
So I am on my first semester of Javafx and I am struggling a bit with this error:
java.io.NotSerializableException: javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
I have a Project which is a Record System of Patients, Consultants and Patients Visits.
I have to add a Consultant, so I can add a Patient to this Consultant, and so I can add Visits to this Patient.
Then, I shall save all this to a Serial File (this is a requirement) where I will read from in the future.
So I found a solution, but dates 9ya, and by the complexity of it I am a little bit reluctant to accept as it says I would have to write down each component/variable of my applications in my writeObject().
Please see the whole project here (please note I am still working on it, so I am aware I have plenty still to do): https://github.com/Gabriela-Pinheiro/OOP_ProjectPart1
The solution I've found: NotSerializableException on SimpleListProperty
Please see some code related to this particular issue that might facilitate the understanding:
Simple SerialStorage class
package model;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerialStorage {
    private static final String fileName = "serialPatientsData.ser";

    
    public static boolean writeFile(Object o) {
        boolean result = true;
        try {
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
            out.writeObject(o);
            out.close();
            file.close();
            System.out.println("Object has been serialized");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("line 24 " + ex);
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    
    public static Object readFile() {
        Object outObject = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file);
            
            outObject = in.readObject();
            in.close();
            file.close();
            System.out.println("Object has been deserialized");
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException is caught 42 " + ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException is caught 44 " + ex);
        }
        return outObject;
    }
}


One of the classes with SimpleStringProperty
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Name implements Serializable{
    private transient StringProperty firstName;
    private transient StringProperty lastName;

    
    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
    }
    
    public StringProperty getFirstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }
    
    public StringProperty getLastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }
    
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }
}

Binding in the AddPatientDialog class

public class AddPatientDialog extends Dialog<Patient> {
    
    private Patient patient;
    private Consultant consultant;
    private AlertBox alertBox = new AlertBox();

    private TextField firstNameInput, lastNameInput, phoneInput;
    private ComboBox<String> comboBox;
    private int selectedIndex = -1;
    private transient Property<Number> indexInput;

    public AddPatientDialog() {
        super();
        this.setTitle("Add Patient");
//      this.patient = p;
        this.patient = new Patient(new Name("", ""), "");
        buildUI();
        setPropertyBinding();
        setResultConverter();
    }

[more code] 

private void setPropertyBinding() {
        firstNameInput.textProperty().bindBidirectional(patient.getName().getFirstNameProperty());
        lastNameInput.textProperty().bindBidirectional(patient.getName().getLastNameProperty());
        phoneInput.textProperty().bindBidirectional(patient.getPhoneProperty());
    }

[more code]

}

A applied the transient to all variables that are StringProperty but still getting the error. I also tried to make the writeFile() to receive and object type Serializable instead of type Object, but no change whatsoever.
So any insights would really be appreciated!!!
Thanks a lot so far!!

I understand that in order to save the data, i.e. consultants, patients and visits, you are trying to serialize all the objects. I don't think this is the best way to save the data and it's not clear (to me) from your question whether you have to use serialization or if you can use any method for saving the data. Can you clarify?

Hi Abra, thanks for your answer. Yes I do have to use serial storage to store my data and load on the page once my application is opened. But I am not sure what is the other way of doing so using Serialization.

Note that "serialization" simply refers to the process of translating objects/data structures into a format suitable for storage and/or transmission. It does not necessarily mean Java Object Serialization. For instance, you could serialize objects to JSON files, CSV files, a SQL database, and so on. So, I would double check if you're required to use Serializable specifically, as that is not a format typically recommended for saving objects to files.

That said, serializing objects with ObjectOutputStream only works for objects which implement Serializable. The built-in JavaFX property implementations do not implement that interface, so they cannot be serialized directly in this way. One way to solve this is to map the objects with JavaFX properties to "data transfer objects" (DTO) that are specially designed to be serialized (e.g., no JavaFX properties). Another solution is to implement readObject / writeObject to customize the serialization or implement Externalizable to do the same with readExternal / writeExternal.

I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the text of your assignment. It could be that you misunderstood the part about using class SerialStorage.

Off-topic, but it doesn't make any sense for the SerialStorage class itself to implement Serializable. Instances of SerialStorage have no state to serialize.

@Slaw thanks you so much, it makes a lot of sense. Probably thats what @Abra was trying to figure it out. Yes, The problem is in my assignment doesn't have a written specs, it's a video explanation, and not very especific. I used the above because it's in line with what we were learning last semestre. But @Abra is right, he doesn't say about using SerialStorage class, he just says Serial Files,  So I guess the options @Slaw gave about using readObject/writeObject will be more appropriate, or the external.  I will have a look into this options. Thank you!

While serializing using Java object serialization is fine, in practice, to enhance readability, backward compatibility, and language and protocol interoperability, often other serialized formats are used (e.g. JSON, GSON, XML, YAML).  Those other serialization types are supported through libraries such as Jackson, GSON, JSON, or JAXB serialization implementations.

In all cases, if using JavaFX properties, you serialize the property values, not the properties themselves. How that is done depends on the chosen technology (Slaw pointed out how to do it for Java serialization).  Either you create converters for each of your objects that extract the values from the property or use the data transfer pattern.  If you make the data transfer objects records or basic Java beans, they will directly serialize to any standard format (JSON/XML/YAML, etc) using a library such as Jackson.  But creation of DTOs is an extra level of indirection.

Thanks a lot @jewelsea. I manage to resolve this issue just now. I ended up having to remove the bindbidirectional, as it wasn't required, and I used something you've mentioned, but I think Slaw also mentioned, I used a converter, and dealt with the inputfields stright in the creation of my object. Also used some strings in my listView (know it's not the best scenario, but it is what solved my case for now).

The final project will be in my GitHub tomorrow, so if anybody interreted just have a look. Again, I really appreciate all inputs from you guys. And will defo have a look in more details on what yous mentioned here to improve my habilities with JavaFX and Java.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
